# Phone authentication in Expo sdk48

Tags: reactjs, firebase, expo

I am referring to the below code for phone authentication in expo sdk 48

https://snack.expo.dev/@sid/firebase-phone-auth?platform=ios

The problem I am facing is that we don't have the "expo-firebase-recaptcha" module supported in 48 so are there any alternatives?